# java OOP ultimate tic tac toe grid

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I'm writing a ultimate tic tac toe in java using OOP concepts and I'm trying to make the board and print it out correctly.
I made Bigboard class which has 9 small boards and each small board consists of 9 boxes that is assigned with an index. When I try printing it, I get this.

```
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 6 | 7 | 8 |

| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 6 | 7 | 8 |

| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 6 | 7 | 8 |
```

instead of this

```
| 0 | 1 | 2 | | 0 | 1 | 2 | | 0 | 1 | 2 | 
| 3 | 4 | 5 | | 3 | 4 | 5 | | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 6 | 7 | 8 | | 6 | 7 | 8 | | 6 | 7 | 8 |

| 0 | 1 | 2 | | 0 | 1 | 2 | | 0 | 1 | 2 | 
| 3 | 4 | 5 | | 3 | 4 | 5 | | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 6 | 7 | 8 | | 6 | 7 | 8 | | 6 | 7 | 8 |

| 0 | 1 | 2 | | 0 | 1 | 2 | | 0 | 1 | 2 | 
| 3 | 4 | 5 | | 3 | 4 | 5 | | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 6 | 7 | 8 | | 6 | 7 | 8 | | 6 | 7 | 8 |
```

big board class print method

```
    void print () {
        System.out.println("printing the " + this.name  + " info....");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < boards.length; i++) {
            if (i!=0 && i%boardColSize == 0) 
                System.out.println();
            boards [i].print();
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

small board class print method

```html
    void print () {
        for (int i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
            if (i!=0 && i%boardColSize == 0) 
                System.out.println();
            boxes [i].print();
        }
        System.out.println("");
```

box class print method

```
    void print() {
        if (Integer.valueOf(placeHolder) == 2 || Integer.valueOf(placeHolder) == 5 || Integer.valueOf(placeHolder) == 8)
            System.out.print("| "+placeHolder + " |");
        else
            System.out.print("| "+ placeHolder + " ");
    }
    
}
```

How do I format the small boards into a 3x3 grid?

Answer (score 0):

Your small board print has a println() call at the end of the method meaning each small board always prints on a new line.
Also to get your desired output you would need to be able to print your small board a row at a time.
ie.

- print small board 0 row 0
- print small board 1 row 0
- print small board 2 row 0
- print line break
- print small board 0 row 1
- ...